# How to read column with column name `0.3` in R?

Tags: r

```
library(ltm)
library(mokken)
data("LSAT")
df_aisp<-aisp(LSAT,search='normal')
df_aisp<-as.data.frame(df_aisp)
#subset if df_aisp$0.3==1
subset(df_aisp,0.3==1)
```

Output of above R script is:

```
[1] 0.3
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Actually,df_aisp is:

```
       0.3
Item 1   1
Item 2   0
Item 3   1
Item 4   0
Item 5   0
```

Which means `subset` give me wrong result.
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use backquotes for column names (to evaluate it as it is) that are not in standard format.  By standard format, names starting with numbers.

```
subset(df_aisp,`0.3`==1)
```

Also, we can specify the column name quoted as such  `[[` or `[` for subsetting

```
df_aisp[df_aisp[,"0.3"] ==1, , drop = FALSE]
```

---

However, we can make the names standard by using `make.names` which will add a prefix `X` to the column name

```
names(df_aisp) <- make.names(names(df_aisp))
names(df_aisp)
#[1] "X0.3"
```

Then, we don't need the backquotes

```
 subset(df_aisp, X0.3 == 1)
 #       X0.3
 #Item 1    1
 #Item 3    1
```